# how to fetch last access TIMESTAMP of a table in oracle?

Tags: oracle

How to fetch the last access date for a table in oracle using the query from Oracle DB?
I am using **select TIMESTAMP from dba_tab_modifications** query it's giving me last updates in table
but I need **last execution of select query statement on a particular table**

Thanks in Advance
Sai Kumar

Comment: maybe you could add a policy (see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm#DBSEG98258) that writes current timestamp in a table on each select

Comment: It's not uncommon to see a column in the table LAST_MODIFIED_DATE and LAST_MODIFIED_BY with a trigger on insert, update set last modifed date to current_timestamp

Comment: @kevinsky: sure but i think he wants a LAST_SELECT_DATE on table level

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not keep this information by default.  You need to enable the appropriate AUDIT rules.  But I'd question what problem you think this will solve.  Auditing every *access* to a table will be a *lot* of audit records.

Comment: He only seems to want the *last* access. I can speculate he seeks answers to the questions we eventually all ask ourselves: What the heck is this table used for? Is it even used at all? (Just a guess, though.)